# Concatenating columns from different files, while skipping the blank lines

Tags: linux, awk

I know it's likely possible to do this with `awk`, but I have no idea how to do it.

Suppose I have the following 2 tab separated files, where there are blank lines that only contain `\n`:

file1:

```
A 1 4
B 2 5
C 3 6

D 7 10
E 8 11
A 9 12
```

file2:

```
E 13 16
F 14 17
G 15 18

H 19 22
I 20 23
J 21 24
```

I want to generate a new file which corresponds to the concatenation of the first 2 columns from file 1 with the third column from file 2, and then the third column from file 1:

final file:

```
A 1 16 4
B 2 17 5
C 3 18 6

D 7 22 10
E 8 23 11
A 9 24 12
```

Note that, in the final file, it's important that the blank lines should be kept blank, and no tabs should be inserted in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple ***paste*** + ***awk*** combination:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '!NF{ print "" }NF{ print $1,$2,$6,$3 }'
```

The output:

```
A 1 16 4
B 2 17 5
C 3 18 6

D 7 22 10
E 8 23 11
A 9 24 12
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the blank lines will contain tabs?  May need to pipe to sed to remove these.

Comment: I've tried this command, but the output file contains tabs in the blank lines

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$3;next} NF{$3=a[FNR] OFS $3} 1' file2 file1
```